# Error in if (Papers[1] > 1) { : valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario

Tags: dataframe

He tenido problemas para que se convierta el archivo m debido a que no se genera el valor de TRUE/FALSE, en ocasiones me dice también que se ha perdido la conexión en R. ¿Alguien tiene idea de lo que puedo hacer para solucionar esto?
Gracias

```
"##Cargar y utilizar función IPAK
ipak <- function(pkg){
  new.pkg <- pkg[!(pkg %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
  if (length(new.pkg)) 
    install.packages(new.pkg, dependencies = TRUE)
  sapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE)
}
packages <- c("bibliometrix") #Pueden poner entre comillas seguido de comas cuantos paquetes necesiten, se instalan y cargan con una sola orden
ipak(packages)
#file
file <- c("1873") 
M <- convert2df(file, dbsource = "scopus", format = "bibtex")
write.csv(M, "M.csv")
#head(M["TC"])
results <- biblioAnalysis(M, sep = ";")
options(width=100)
S <- summary(object = results, k = 10, pause = FALSE)
S$MostProdCountries
S$MostRelSources"
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece estar en la definición de `file`. Si deseas indicar la ubicación de un archivo debes incluir la extensión, por ejemplo: `"1873.txt"`, `"1873.csv"`, `"1873.xlsx"`, etc.